# Reducer running twice when using useReducer and React Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-reducer

I am kind of running my head into a wall on a weird circumstance using the React Context API along with the useReducer and useContext hooks.

Here is my main store.

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import { Reducers } from './Reducers';
import { surveys } from '../../testData.json';

export const context = createContext();
const { Provider } = context;

export const Store = ({ children }) => {
  const [store, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducers, {
    editSurvey: { display: false },
    surveys,
  });
  return <Provider value={{ store, dispatch }}>{children}</Provider>;
};
```

Here is my Reducers function and my Action types:

```
import { Actions } from './Actions';
const { DISPLAY_NEW_SURVEY, HIDE_SURVEY } = Actions;
export const Reducers = (state, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  console.log(state, action);
  switch (type) {
    case DISPLAY_NEW_SURVEY:
      return { ...state, editSurvey: { display: true } };
    case HIDE_SURVEY:
      return { ...state, editSurvey: { display: false } };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```
export const Actions = {
  DISPLAY_NEW_SURVEY: 'DISPLAY_NEW_SURVEY',
  HIDE_SURVEY: 'HIDE_SURVEY',
};
```

I have a display property inside my edit property which is used to conditionally render a react portal, see below:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { EditSurveyPortal } from '../EditSurvey/EditSurveyPortal';
import { context } from '../../store/Store';

export const NavItem = ({ name, NavImage }) => {
  const { dispatch } = useContext(context);
  return (
    <div
      id={name}
      style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
      onClick={() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'DISPLAY_NEW_SURVEY' });
      }}
    >
      <NavImage alt={name} width={10} height={10} />
      <EditSurveyPortal />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';
import { context } from '../../store/Store';
import { EditSurvey } from './EditSurvey';

export const EditSurveyPortal = () => {
  const {
    store: {
      editSurvey: { display },
    },
    dispatch,
  } = useContext(context);
  return display
    ? createPortal(
        <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-screen h-screen z-10 flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-400 bg-opacity-50">
          <EditSurvey />
        </div>,
        document.getElementById('root'),
      )
    : null;
};
```

And here is the actual edit survey component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardHeader } from '../Utility/Card';
import { Close } from '../Images/Close';

export const EditSurvey = ({ dispatch }) => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader className="flex justify-between align-center">
        <div className="inline-block relative rounded">
          <span className="absolute top-0 l-0 bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 rounded-l px-2 py-1">
            Title
          </span>
          <input type="text" className="rounded p-1" />
        </div>
        <div
          className="text-gray-800"
          style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'HIDE_SURVEY' });
          }}
        >
          <Close width={8} height={8} />
        </div>
      </CardHeader>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

My issue is that when I click the close button on the portal, it dispatches HIDE_SURVEY then immediately dispatches DISPLAY_NEW_SURVEY:

[image: Screenshot of Page]

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: where are you dispatching `DISPLAY_NEW_SURVEY` action?

Comment: @PrateekThapa I edited the post and added the component which calls the `DISPLAY_NEW_SURVEY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Bubbling, mate.

The problem here is that your `EditSurvey` is below the clickable area of NavItem.
What is happening here is that when you clicked on that div in your `EditSurvey`, it registers the click on that div first and then bubbles up to your NavItem clickable div. This is basically what is called as `event-bubbling`

You could learn about event bubbling and capturing [here](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

Also, you could check the event bubbling issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ug7ktg) as well

In order to stop the event from bubbling up, you could simply stop the propagation of the event.

```
<div
    className="text-gray-800"
    style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
    onClick={(event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      dispatch({ type: 'HIDE_SURVEY' });
    }}
  >
    <Close width={8} height={8} />
  </div>
```

Comment: Dude, thank you so much!

I've gotta do some research on event bubbling, thanks for the links!